# Error passing post_content to function

Tags: plugin-development

The purpose of this function is to simply wrap the first occurrence of the keyword in bold tags. I'm getting an error on the line marked below.

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: error parsing attribute name in Entity, line: 4 in C:\xampplite\htdocs\testsite\wp-content\plugins\mylugin\test.php on line 40

Is this the correct way to pass the post_content object?

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'my_bold_keyword' );
function my_bold_keyword($content){
  $myKeyword = "test 123";
  $d = new DOMDocument();
  $d->loadHTML($content['post_content']); //ERROR OCCURS HERE
  $x = new DOMXpath($d);
  $Matches = $x->query("//text()[contains(.,$myKeyword) and not(ancestor::h1) and not(ancestor::h2) and not(ancestor::h3) and not(ancestor::h4) and not(ancestor::h5) and not(ancestor::h6)]");
  if($Matches && $Matches->length > 0){
    $myText = $Matches->item(0);
    // need to wrap #myText in <b> wrapper
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@Scott B:**

Here's a modified version of what you have that resolves the error *(although the XPath does not match; I'm not an XPath guru so can't help with the proper XPath syntax):*

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'my_bold_keyword', 10, 2 );
function my_bold_keyword( $data, $postarr ) {
  $myKeyword = "test 123";
  $d = new DOMDocument();
  $d->loadHTML($postarr['post_content']); //ERROR NO LONGER OCCURS HERE
  $x = new DOMXpath($d);
  $Matches = $x->query("//text()[contains(.,$myKeyword) and not(ancestor::h1) and not(ancestor::h2) and not(ancestor::h3) and not(ancestor::h4) and not(ancestor::h5) and not(ancestor::h6)]");
  if($Matches && $Matches->length > 0){
    $myText = $Matches->item(0);
    // need to wrap #myText in <b> wrapper
  }
  return $content;
}
```

P.S. About that PhpStorm... '-)

Comment: I've downloaded the trial and looking forward to checking it out. Thanks again for the nudge ;)

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm getting the same error with $postarr['post_content'] that I got before.

Comment: @Scott B: My bad. Just when I think I can get away with not testing what I post... I did not fix the XPath to work correct because I'd have to learn XPath to do that, but I fixed your crashing issue from your original code.  *(Hint: PhpStorm+Zend Debugger... :)*

Comment: @Scott B: BTW, definitely start with the [Early Access Program version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP); it's much better than the shipping version and very stable: